# ORACLE JDBC: DriverManager or OracleDataSource

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

While trying to connect to my `Oracle 11.1.0.7.0` database using jdbc with the `ojdbc6.jar` of the matching version, I found two variants.
Assuming a string **DBURL** of the form

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//#DBSERV#:#DBPORT#/#DBSID#
```

where those hashed words ('...') are filled correct, they (the variants) look like

1. ods=new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
   ods.setPassword(Datenbankpasswort);
   ods.setUser(Datenbankuser);
   ods.setURL(DBURL);
   dbconn=ods.getConnection;
2. java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
   dbconn=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,Datenbankuser,Datenbankpasswort);

of course followed by `dbconn.getConnection();`.
So far, I think both should work - but I'm interested which way is better? Maybe one is deprecated?
Further I can only connect with variant 1. Maybe I missed something in variant 2.
I'm interested in any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) is the preferred way to provide connection to a database.
This kind of high-level object "do" the job for you and access to lower classes, like the [DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

You can find some implementations of `DataSource` more powerful, where connections are pooled and reusable: [ConnectionPoolDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html)

`DataSource` are typically configured and registered into a JNDI tree.
Usually, application/web servers like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) offer capability to configure (and share) a DataSource.